# Mocha Chai vue testing a vue component : this.$notify is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, mocha.js

I'm using this component : https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification

Since then, all of my Mocha chai test units are failing .

```
this.$notify is not a function
```

This is my login spec :

```
// Importing The testing library 
import { expect } from "chai";
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

// Importing  The component I need to test
import Login from "@/components/Login.vue";


// Mounting the component as in real life 
const wrapper = mount(Login);


describe("Login test", () => {

  it("getAuth() to be a function", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.getAuth).to.be.a("function");
  });

});
```

I've tried out mount, shallowMount, render with no luck .

Any workaround ?

I'm calling vue-notification in main.js like this :

```
import Notifications from "vue-notification";
Vue.use(Notifications);
```

Thank you !

**EDIT :**
Ive tried to add

```
const $notify = require('vue-notification')
```

To my Login.vue component with no luck

**EDIT 2 :** Tried to call the function like this with no luck :

```
 this.$root.$notify({
        group: 'foo',
        title: 'Hello ',
        text: 'Cool'
        });

[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$root.$notify is not a function"
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT : ***** Resolved by me ****** *** 
 I was badly importing vue . Please see my working **login.spec.js**  testing file there :

```
// THE ASSERTION LIBRARY
import { expect } from "chai";

// THE TESTING LIBRARY
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

// THE COMPONENT THAT I WANT TO TEST
import Login from "@/components/Login.vue";

// THE EXTERNAL COMPONENTS LINKED TO MY LOGIN COMPONENT  THAT I NEED TO JOIN
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
 import {
    required,
    minLength,
    between
} from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
import Notifications from "vue-notification";
import velocity      from 'velocity-animate'
Vue.use(Notifications, { velocity });


// THE WRAPPER CONTAIN MY LOGIN MOUNTED COMPONENT, JUST LIKE IN THE REAL LIFE
const wrapper = mount(Login)

describe("Login test", () => {

  it("getAuth() to be a function", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.getAuth).to.be.a("function");
  });

});
```

[image: success result]